# What is oob in func (*UDPConn) ReadMsgUDP?

Tags: go, udp

[This link](http://beej.us/298C/oob_overview.html) has information about OOB in TCP.

> With out-of-band data we want the byte-stream service layer on the
>   sending side to send this data before any other data that it has
>   buffered. Similarly we want the receiving end to pass this data to its
>   user process ahead of any data that it might have buffered.

But what about UDP?

In golang, the `ReadMsgUDP` function requires an `oob` byte slice.

```
func (c *UDPConn) ReadMsgUDP(b, oob []byte) (n, oobn, flags int, addr *UDPAddr, err error)
```

What is the `oob` for? Are there any use cases in open source code? Or should I use `PacketConn` instead of `UDPConn`?

Comment: My take is that this call merely wraps `recv(2)` syscall which has the `oob` parameter no matter which kind of socket it is. On my system, `man 2 send` says `oob` is only used with `SOCK_STREAM`sockets, and UDP are not them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I tried, when you want other infomation(such as pktinfo) to get local address with setting syscall.setsockoption, you will need it. This happens when you don't want connection-oriented UDP.

Comment: But I have no idea about the para "flags" as far

Answer (score 1):

OOB in ReadMsgUDP() is misnamed.  It is the socket ancillary channel.  It has absolutely nothing to do with TCP OOB (out-of-band) data.

If you're looking at POSIX manpages, it is the "msg" parameter for recvmsg(2), refer also to cmsg(3).